# Why the following trivial Rx.NET does not print any numbers?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);

            var dst = new Subject<int>();
            var res = dst
                .SelectMany(async arg =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                    Console.WriteLine(arg);
                    return Unit.Default;
                })
                .DefaultIfEmpty();
            Observable.Range(0, 10).Subscribe(dst);

            await res;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect 10 numbers on the output, in reality I get none. Why?

Comment: This is hardly a "trivial" use of Rx.

Comment: +1 What do you want to know or be able to do? IMO most Rx solutions do not involve the use of Subject, but plenty of Rx issues do.

Comment: I want to understand why this code does not work - that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting any values because `Observable.Range(0, 10).Subscribe(dst);` runs on the current thread to completion and, so by the time `await res` is called `dst` doesn't have any new values.

You can do either (1) `var dst = new ReplaySubject<int>();` or (2) `Observable.Range(0, 10).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Subscribe(dst);` to get values out of your code.

Either way, this isn't trivial Rx.

---

I thought Lee's comment was particularly well written so I thought it was worth adding here:

> i.e. `Observable.Range(0, 10).Subscribe(dst);` pumps 10 values into the subject immediately. Then you invoke the subscription on `res`. The values are gone. `Subject<T>` doesn't cache values. It would be like raise an event 10 times then attaching an event handler.

Comment: i.e. `Observable.Range(0, 10).Subscribe(dst);` pumps 10 values into the subject immediately. Then you invoke the subscription on `res`. The values are gone. `Subject<T>` doesn't cache values. It would be like raise an event 10 times then attaching an eventhandler.